# Find the area ratio between ABC and the hatched triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

Could you help me?

Find the area ratio between ABC and the hatched triangle.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An application of Routh's Theorem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%27s_theorem   More precisely, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-seventh_area_triangle

Answer (score 1):

Take the segment $AB$ as horizontal. If one moves the point $C$ along the $x$ axis, stretching the rest of the figure accordingly, every area will be preserved. If one then moves $C$ along the $y$ axis, every area will be scaled by a constant factor. Therefore, we can assume $\bigtriangleup ABC$ to be equilateral, and we can make its circumcircle the unit circle WLOG.

Let $X=CA_1\cap AB_1$, $Y=AB_1\cap BC_1$, $Z=BC_1\cap CA_1$, so that $\bigtriangleup XYZ$ is the shaded triangle. We can represent each point in our diagram as a complex number. We first calculate $$A_1=\frac{2A+B}{3},$$ $$B_1=\frac{2B+C}{3},$$ $$C_1=\frac{2C+A}{3}.$$ By Menelaus on $\bigtriangleup ABB_1$, $\frac{|B_1-X|}{|X-A|}=\frac{4}{3}$, so that subsequently $$X=\frac{4A+3B_1}{7}=\frac{4A+2B+C}{7}=A\left(4+2\omega+\omega^2\right),$$ and analogously, $$Y=B\left(4+2\omega+\omega^2\right),$$ $$Z=C\left(4+2\omega+\omega^2\right),$$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$. Therefore, $\bigtriangleup XYZ$ is just $\bigtriangleup ABC$ scaled down by a factor of $|4+2\omega+\omega^2|=\sqrt{7}$, and the ratio of their areas is $\boxed{7}$.

Comment: It is quite hard proof, could you explain it more.

Comment: Here's an abridged version. Since shearing, stretching and translating preserve ratios of areas, I can take $\bigtriangleup ABC$ to be an equilateral triangle with vertices on the unit circle. With some simple calculations, we can then find out that in this specific case, the shaded triangle is the image of the original triangle after multiplying by the complex number $4+2e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}+e^\frac{4i\pi}{3}$. This implies that the ratio of their areas is the square of the magnitude of this number, which turns out to $7$.